# Move a file to a specific folder

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to move a file to a specified folder but I can't.
This is the code:

```
  public static void moveToRightDirectory(File song, String album) throws IOException {
    if(album.endsWith(" ")) { 
      album = album.substring(0, album.length() - 1);
    }
    String pathDirectory = selectedDir + "\\" + album;
    File dir = new File(pathDirectory);
    System.out.println("dir.exists(): " + dir.exists());
    if(dir.exists()) { 
      Files.move(song.toPath(), dir.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
      //System.out.println(song.renameTo(dir));
    }
    else { 
      boolean success = (new File(pathDirectory)).mkdirs();
      if(!success) {
        System.out.println("Error creating directory.");
      }
      else {
        Files.move(song.toPath(), dir.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
        //System.out.println(song.renameTo(dir));
        //FileUtils.moveFile(song, dir);
      }
    }
  }
```

I know there are other message about this (from these I was inspired) but I wasn't able to solve so I would ask for your help.

I would like to move the `song` file in the folder `dir`. To do this I have tried several methods:

- `Files.move` -> The following errors are generated:

  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 55: C:\Users...\dir
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
      at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.File.toPath(Unknown Source)
      at createDir.CreateDirectory.moveToRightDirectory(CreateDirectory.java:73)
      at createDir.CreateDirectory.createDirectory(CreateDirectory.java:40)
      at gui.DirChooser.actionPerformed(DirChooser.java:54)
      at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
      at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
      at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
      at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
      at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
      at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
- `song.renameTo(dir)` -> It does nothing.
- `FileUtils.moveFile(song, dir);` -> Eclipse does not find `FileUtils`. I did the import of `java.lang.Object.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` but the error becomes "The import java.lang.Object.org can not be resolved."

How can I fix?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the actual question, but, based on the error message

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 55:

I'm guessing your code isn't getting rid of the trailling whitespaces properly.

Try

```
album = album.trim();
```

Instead of

```
if(album.endsWith(" ")) { 
  album = album.substring(0, album.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I edited like you suggested but now the error is: `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\ila\Desktop\Adele\Cold shoulder.mp3 -> C:\Users\ila\Desktop\Adele\19: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`...

Comment: Well, that's is an unrelated error. I recommend you make a research with this new stacktrace.

Comment: @Sekkur I searched the internet but haven't yet managed to solve .. you have any advice?

Comment: kill your music player thats using it. something has its resources

Comment: @Busturdust Hello, thanks for the advice. I have no music player open except Spotify but has nothing to do with .mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/

Maybe this will be of assistance

Step 1 : Rename File

```
import java.io.File;

public class MoveFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try{

           File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");

           if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + afile.getName()))){
            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
           }else{
           System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
           }

         }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Step 2: Copy and delete

```
   import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MoveFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

        try{

            File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");
            File bfile =new File("C:\\folderB\\Afile.txt");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the answer he is looking for

Comment: if that is the case then a summary of the link should be made in the answer in case the link goes dead

Comment: @Busturdust thanks for the link, but I had already read and already applied. It does not work then I probably did something wrong but I don't know what..

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not appropriate for SO, since non-locally hosted data isn't guaranteed to be around.  It's fine to include a link to an outside source as a clarification or expansion on your answer, but you need to have the actual answer in your post as well.